# Getting command argument in javascript

Tags: javascript, commandargument

In the web page, I have some codes like

```
<span commandArgument="a">A</span>
<span commandArgument="b">B</span>
```

I want to use javascript to get the commandArgument values of the spans, and the code I wrote is

```
var spans = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
var value = spans[0].commandArgument;
```

It works in IE but fails in Firefox.
IE gets value = "a" and Firefox gets value = undefined.
Is there any method to get the values that works in both browser? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getAttribute) from the [methods of the DOM element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element#Methods).

This method works in old browsers as well according to the [compatibility sheet](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html) of quirskmode.org

```
var value = spans[0].getAttribute('commandArgument');
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `.getAttribute("commandArgument")`?

...and its ugly cousin must be mentioned, `.setAttribute("commandArgument", "c")`